# how to start activity from android service

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service

I am trying to start a new activity from inside a service. I am using the following code, as many have suggested:

```
Intent i = new Intent(m_Context, myActivity.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
m_Context.startActivity(i);
```

But, it gives an android.content.ActivityNotFoundException and says that I have to add the activity to my manifest. But the problem is that this is a service and has no manifest. Is there a way to start an activity without entering it in a manifest file?

Comment: All activities must be declared in your manifest file, AndroidManifest.xml, using an <activity> element.

Comment: Try searching on Google before asking a question. This is the basic about Android and I believe there are alot of answers about this question.

Comment: @adneal: the issue is that this code is inside a .jar file which will be distributed. So What i really want to do is somehow start an activity from within a library. (compiled with an Android.mk and 'make' and without using Eclipse)

Comment: @osayilgan - i did search. everyone says that  it cant be done without a manifest. please see my comment above. thanks.

Comment: @jack_black next time try to make the question more clear. I couldn't understand it clearly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to distribute your code through a jar, you need to add the activity on the manifest in the app which will include the jar.

The only way to start an activity is to include it in a manifest.

Comment: thank you for actually understanding the question and answering. I will check this and mark your answer.

Answer (score 0):

try this code it may help

```
Intent in=new Intent().setClass(MyAlarmService.this,Reminder.class);
in.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(in);
```